# Angular 6: how to dynamically add and delete a row of 2 textboxes on a button click using angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, angular6

I have a angular project whereby users can click on the add button to produce 2 more textboxes at every click and similarly delete the corresponding row on a button click.The maximum of 5 rows should be allowed to create and one default empty row of textboxes at the begining.

The data entered needs to be used for 2 way data binding while it can be helpful while editing.

The following code i got from here which i have modified a bit with numbers has the required functionality but i need the same in angular 6. Since i have less idea in jquery and am new to angular please help me with this with the addon condition of having a row of textboxes as default at the begining.

```js
var x=1;
var count=0;

//click Event for the add button
$('body').on('click','#add',function(){
  if(count <= 5){
    //add the two inputs + the reset button to a div with class 'line' then append 
    //this div to #div

    $('#div').append("<div class='line'><input type='text' id='txta"+ x +"'><span class='wordtab'></span><input type='text' id='txtb"+ x +"'><button class='delete' value='Reset'>Reset</button></div>");
    count++;
    x++
  }
  else
    alert("Maximum 5 Skills");
});

//click Event for the delete button
$('body').on('click','.delete',function(){

  //when the user click on delete get the parent div with class 'line' of clickable 
  //button and remove it

  $(this).closest('.line').remove(); 
  count--;
});
```

```css
.wordtab 
{
  min-width: 85px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.line{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button id='add' value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below procedure for addition of dynamic content using angular 6/7:

1. Create a new angular project.
2. Install bootstrap and Toaster as we are going to use it further using following command:

```
npm install bootstrap  

npm install ngx-toastr --save
```

3. add the reference for bootstrap and toaster in the angular.json file.

```
"Styles":[
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
   "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
]
```

4.Create a new component using following command

```
ng g c grid-view --routing
```

5. Type the following command to generate the model file for the class.

```
ng g class grid.model
```

6.Open the app.module.ts file present in the root folder and add the references there.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';  
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';  
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  
import { GridViewComponent } from './grid-view/grid-view.component';  
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';  

@NgModule({  
  declarations: [  
    AppComponent,  
    GridViewComponent,  
  ],  
  imports: [  
    BrowserModule,  
    AppRoutingModule,  
    FormsModule ,  
    BrowserAnimationsModule,  
    ToastrModule.forRoot()  
  ],  
  providers: [],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]  
})  
export class AppModule { }
```

7.Open app.component.html file and add the code in it.

```
<div class="container">     
     <app-grid-view></app-grid-view>    
 </div>
```

8.Open the index.html file and add the reference for font-awesome.(If you want to use font awesome icons).

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">    
<head>    
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <title>DynamicGrid</title>    
  <base href="/">    

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">    
</head>    
<body>    
  <app-root></app-root>    
</body>    
</html>
```

9.Open the grid.model.ts file and add the class in it.

```
export class DynamicGrid{     
    title1:string;  
    title2:string;  
    title3:string;  
}
```

10.Open the grid-view.component.html file add the HTML code in it.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">    
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">    
        <thead>    
            <tr>    
                <th>Action</th>    
                <th>Title 1</th>    
                <th>Title 2</th>    
                <th>Title 3</th>    
            </tr>    
        </thead>    
        <tbody>    
             <tr *ngFor="let dynamic of dynamicArray; let i = index;">    
              <td (click)="deleteRow(i)">    
                <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>    
              </td>    
                <td>    
                  <input [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title1" class="form-control" type="text" />    
                </td>    
                <td>    
                  <input [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control" type="text" />    
                </td>    
                <td>    
                  <input [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title3" class="form-control" type="text"/>    
                </td>    
            </tr>    
            <tr>    
              <td (click)="addRow(i)">    
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>    
              </td>    
            </tr>    
        </tbody>    
    </table>    
  </div>
```

11.Finally, write the below code for the grid-view.component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';  
import { DynamicGrid } from '../grid.model';  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-grid-view',  
  templateUrl: './grid-view.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./grid-view.component.css']  
})  
export class GridViewComponent implements OnInit {  

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }  

  dynamicArray: Array<DynamicGrid> = [];  
  newDynamic: any = {};  
  ngOnInit(): void {  
      this.newDynamic = {title1: "", title2: "",title3:""};  
      this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);  
  }  

  addRow(index) {    
      this.newDynamic = {title1: "", title2: "",title3:""};  
      this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);  
      this.toastr.success('New row added successfully', 'New Row');  
      console.log(this.dynamicArray);  
      return true;  
  }  

  deleteRow(index) {  
      if(this.dynamicArray.length ==1) {  
        this.toastr.error("Can't delete the row when there is only one row", 'Warning');  
          return false;  
      } else {  
          this.dynamicArray.splice(index, 1);  
          this.toastr.warning('Row deleted successfully', 'Delete row');  
          return true;  
      }  
  }  

}
```

You can also follow the link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamically-add-and-remove-row-in-angular-7/